# Coldfusion 10+ - CFSCHEDULE - what if task already running

Tags: coldfusion

I want to create a CFschedule task to run every 30 seconds and was wondering what would happen if a Task tries to fire up while the previous task is still running - does it wait or die or ???

Answer (score 1):

cfschedule doesnt care much about the content of your jobs, think of it like cron daemon on Linux. Its just the scheduling agent.

If you need to ensure only one job of a certain type is running its up to you to implement some kind of busy/locking behavior, probably using some kind of a datastore such as a relational database, plain files (ala the presence of a file indicates in-process, then delete it right before job completion, this would be a good use of the `onComplete` handler), redis, etc.

Comment: If the schedule is running on a single server only, [named locking](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cflock.html) is available in CF.

Comment: Thanks all - good ideas there - I actually am dealing with database rows in a <CFTRANSACTION> block, so there is no risk of processing the same rows twice.  If Task 1 starts and selects 50 rows from the queue table to action (via a select and update loop) and then Task 2 starts before the processing of these rows complete, then Task 2 shouldn't do anything if no additional rows to action exist.

Comment: You have to store data that keeps track of what rows are being processed.